# How to sign a piece of data from JavaScript running in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, digital-signature

Assuming users have a personal certificate already setup (visible in Internet Options / Content / Certificates), how can I write in JavaScript code that invokes the Microsoft CryptoAPI, asking users to sign piece of data with their personal certificate?

Answer (score 1):

Use **CAPICOM**  of  Internet explorer

this will read all certificate from browser and sign piece of data with there selected personal certificate

Comment: Romani, I see CAPICOM is deprecated, might not be supported in future version of Windows, and doesn't seem to come out of the box at least on Vista and Windows 7. Do you know if there are any other alternatives that would work out of the box on IE?

Comment: then if you r using java, I have not checked but you can create applet to do that.